# WSO2 API manager failed to open a published API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting this exception when trying to open a published API

[2021-05-23 10:45:35,591] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9223372036854776000"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source) ~[json-simple_1.1.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source) ~[json-simple_1.1.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[json-simple_1.1.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[json-simple_1.1.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[json-simple_1.1.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.definitions.OASParserUtil.getAPIDefinition_aroundBody64(OASParserUtil.java:1016) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.definitions.OASParserUtil.getAPIDefinition(OASParserUtil.java:998) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAPIForPublishing_aroundBody10(APIUtil.java:750) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAPIForPublishing(APIUtil.java:634) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getApiForPublishing_aroundBody16(AbstractAPIManager.java:474) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getApiForPublishing(AbstractAPIManager.java:473) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getAPIbyUUID_aroundBody20(AbstractAPIManager.java:517) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getAPIbyUUID(AbstractAPIManager.java:491) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.getAPIByID(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:4260) ~[classes/:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisApiIdGet(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:470) ~[classes/:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisApiIdGet(ApisApi.java:380) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_291]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_291]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
[Photo Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMF4r.png)

Comment: What is the APIM version? I believe this error is thrown on the publisher's side. Were you able to open this API in devportal? What was the last change you have done? This seems like you have provided the number in the place of the string.

Comment: this error happened when I am trying edit the API definition I am using WSO2 API Manager v 4.0.0 and I am not using any number values I am just remove a word from an resouce url from api/v1/test/ to /test/

Comment: Please add the complete swagger definition.

Comment: Editing the resource paths didn't produce any errors when testing it locally. So the problem might be due to the swagger. Would be useful if you share the swagger definition.

Comment: The problem was with my swagger but the generated error was not showing that

Comment: When you copy the swagger definition directly to the publisher swagger editor did it show any errors? Did you try to open the definition in the standard swagger editor and got any errors?